Custom configuration for NvChad is not working
 "nvchad.mappings"

-- add yours here

local map = vim.keymap.set

map("n", ";", ":", { desc = "CMD enter command mode" })

map("i", "jk", "<ESC>")

-- Move lines up/down

map("n", "<A-Down>", ":m .+1<CR>", { desc = "Move line down" })

map("n", "<A-j>", ":m .+1<CR>", { desc = "Move line down" })

map("n", "<A-Up>", ":m .-2<CR>", { desc = "Move line up" })


the above code is in lua/mappings.lua
qns 1: . i want to add some custom keyboard shortcuts but this configuration is not working . i dont know why.

qns 2 : (this is expected to be a default behaviour) also when i open any code in nvim "alt + i" is not working which is for opening a floating terminal. it inly works when i open  the neovim app(a black app) . instead of opening that terminal i go into thewinsert mode
so i researched for how to make configuration and mostly are old file structure. https://github.com/mgastonportillo/nvchad-config   used this reference to change my configuration but nothing happens.

If you are using the  version 2.5, the configuration structure has changed

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
